# The Neo-Tethys Sea, in Full

Tags: climate, geography, earth-like, geology, sea

In [Turning the Mediterranean into a sort of Neotethys](/questions/19008/turning-the-mediterranean-into-a-sort-of-neotethys?rq=1), I focused only on tilting Africa to the extent that Gibraltar has become an isthmus connecting Africa to Europe, thus opening passage to the Indian Ocean at the expense of shutting the door to the Atlantic, thereby creating the [Neo-Tethys Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethys_Ocean). 
This scenario is slightly different:

- Africa stays right where it is, but it is shaped differently, as though sea levels have risen by 77 meters.
- Physically absent from this scenario are the land masses of Israel, Turkey and Iran.
- The Caspian Basin is not land below sea level—it’s water.
- The average depth has deepened from 1500 meters to about 3767 meters.

With these mentioned changes, how would they affect the North African/European climate and landscape?

Comment: Physically absent -- as in the land mass isn't there?

Comment: Hello John, you frequently ask questions with false precision. 77 meters? 3767 meters? There is no way you are going to get answers with four-digit accuracy.

Comment: How are Turkey and Iran Absent?  Are they also ocean?

Comment: Having wiped out the drivers of about 90 percent of known history, this question is way too broad.

Comment: @SerbanTanasa  Correct.

Comment: @o.m.  What do you mean by "false precision"?

Comment: @JohnWDailey, when you ask a question with four significant digits, you imply that there is a difference between 3766 m and 3767 m. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_precision

Comment: I'd appreciate it if someone actually gives me an answer and not a wave of dismissal.

Comment: Why Israel? It’s tiny and doesn’t border Turkey/Anatolia/Asia minor or Iran/Persia – do you mean [Levant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levant) (in the modern sense)? What about the Arabian peninsula, Sinai and Red Sea in particular? A crude map would help a bunch.

Comment: @Crissov  Because Israel had the DEAD Sea.  Too salty to drink, and so physically getting rid of the country might give it life again.

Comment: Started a meta discussion: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2981/world-under-ice-questions-too-broad